# Gitlab Taking Forever to Load - Using Apache

Tags: apache, gitlab

Alright so I just installed Gitlab on my Ubuntu 14.04. I wanted it to run on Apache instead of the usual nginx because I have Lets Encrypt configured to use my Apache server.

I changed around the config here: http://pastebin.com/raw/KctmGFq7

By following this guide: http://kevingoedecke.me/2015/09/17/setup-gitlab-on-debian-7-with-existing-apache-webserver/

Gitlab is not responding from the outside. Okay, why not try it from the inside? Nope, it just keeps loading forever. I did reconfigure Gitlab and restarted my Apache and server many times. Nothing.

Whats wrong?

Comment: Put the code in question itself, instead of pastebin links

Comment: @hjpotter92 but its pretty big. Its kind of cleaner for a pastebin link